# Cross link in Tarjan's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, tarjans-algorithm

I'm reading [Tarjan's paper on scc](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~gilbert/cs240a/old/cs240aSpr2011/slides/TarjanDFS.pdf).

In the paper, the lowlink of a given vertex is defined as:

> *LOWLINK (v) is the smallest vertex which is in the same component as v
>   and is reachable by traversing zero or more tree arcs followed by at most one
>   frond or cross-link.*

I can't come up with any situation the path from two vertexes in a given scc via a 
cross link edge, since the whole scc should be in one tree derived by a dfs search. Can anyone explain this a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple:

You index the graph as you traverse it, when you are returning from the recursion, you note for each node, which least index is reachable from it. To reach lower index than the specified node already has, there has to be a cross link or a frond link. Because when you reach an yet open node with lower index, it means that you have found a node in the same scc, it is easy to follow, that all nodes with the same lowlink are in the same component ([visualization of the algorithm](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/44220/Tarjans-algorithm)).

Answer (score 0):

Cross-link edges, according to Tarjan's paper that you've linked, are connections between trees in our depth-first search forest. So if we go down a long path in our search tree, then go down another path and find that further down it connects back to the first tree, the edge is called a cross-link edge.

Frond edges, on the other hand, are described as an edge that goes back to a previous vertex within the same search tree. So if we had a graph that went in a circle with the final edge connecting back to the start edge, that final edge is called a frond edge.

Both of these edges are necessary for vertices to be in the same strongly-connected components.

I think I have found an example that is exactly what you are looking for. Consider the following graph:

[image: Directed graph]

Taking a quick look, you can see that there are essentially two smaller strongly-connected components that make up one larger one.

When we perform depth-first search on the graph, we visit vertices in the following order: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`. So we first visit the subtree `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, then the subtree `6, 7`. It is important that `7` take on the lowlink value of 3, which occurs when we examine the cross-link edge from `7` to `3`. Otherwise, when running the algorithm, `LOWLINK(6)=6` and 6 and 7 would be placed in their own separate strongly connected component.

The depth-first search tree is shown below for further clarity. Frond and cross-link edges are shown as dashed red lines.

[image: Depth-first search tree of the previous directed graph]

Upon running the algorithm, our vertices have the following final low-link values:

```
0: 0
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 0
5: 0
6: 3
7: 3
```

Vertex `0` is the only one that has its own low-link value, so upon returning to `0` in our recursion, all other vertices will be on the stack. So all vertices are placed in the same connected component. Notice once again that if we didn't consider the cross-link edge from `7` to `3`, this would not have worked.